# How to show hide columns when 2 or more checkboxes are checked in a choice field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery

Struggling with this for a while:
I think I need an OR statement somewhere
I am trying to hide the columns when either Male or Female boxes are selected

```
$(function(){

    $("nobr:contains('If Male')").closest('tr').hide();
    $("nobr:contains('If Female')").closest('tr').hide();
    $("nobr:contains('Address')").closest('tr').hide();

    $("span[title='Male']>input").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))|| $("span[title='Female']>input").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
            $("nobr:contains('If Male')").closest('tr').show();
            $("nobr:contains('If Female')").closest('tr').show();
            $("nobr:contains('Address')").closest('tr').show();
        }else{

            $("nobr:contains('If Male')").closest('tr').hide();
            $("nobr:contains('If Female')").closest('tr').hide();
            $("nobr:contains('Address')").closest('tr').hide();
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: You want to hide all three `tr`'s when either Male or Female  is selected?  Or you want to hide one `tr` or the other depending which one is selected?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure I am following what you are wanting to do, but assuming that you want to run the exact same block of code when **either** the `span[title='Male']>input` **OR** the `span[title='Female']>input` changes, then you just need to put both selectors in the same string separated by a comma (`"span[title='Male']>input, span[title='Female']>input"`), so that your code would look like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("nobr:contains('If Male')").closest('tr').hide();
    $("nobr:contains('If Female')").closest('tr').hide();
    $("nobr:contains('Address')").closest('tr').hide();

    $("span[title='Male']>input, span[title='Female']>input").change(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("nobr:contains('If Male')").closest('tr').show();
            $("nobr:contains('If Female')").closest('tr').show();
            $("nobr:contains('Address')").closest('tr').show();
        } else {
            $("nobr:contains('If Male')").closest('tr').hide();
            $("nobr:contains('If Female')").closest('tr').hide();
            $("nobr:contains('Address')").closest('tr').hide();
        }
    });
});
```